# Converting BitArray to Binary

Tags: python, string, binary, hex, bitarray

I'm trying to make a simple compressor (I think the algorithm is done) but when trying to get read the bytes from a file and converting them to binary i'm not able to do it.

I have a BitArray that should be referring to a file 'test.png'

```
b = BitArray(bytes=open('test.png', 'rb').read())
```

And when I print b I get:

```
0x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000031000000369080200000014b648a3000000017352474200aece1ce90000000467414d410000b18f0bfc6105000000097048597300000ec300000ec301c76fa86400008e9149444154785eeddd07781445e3c771ae25744215044445b0e3abd81b8205ebabd87dedbdf7de...
```

I'm trying to get the binary value as following:

```
b = bin(int(str(b), 16))
print(b)
```

But I get the following error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16`

I'm wondering if this is because the number is very large?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you ever considered using `bytearray`? It's the built in type for working with binary data (i.e. files). Reading file will look somewhat like this: `bytes = bytearray(open('test.png', 'rb').read())`; writing: `open('test.png', 'rb').write(bytes)`. It's also considrerd a good practice to either `close()` files after you've opened them or use them withing a context manager (e.g. `with open('test.png', 'rb') as file:`). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I used `bytearray` and after that `binary = bin(int.from_bytes(bytes, byteorder=sys.byteorder))` and it worked!